# ValueEventListner wont run the first time activity is loaded

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I don't understand why the listener doesn't run the first time the activity is loaded. Here is the code snippet.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_health_summary);

    ArrayList<SummaryPestQuadratHillIncidence> arrayListSummary = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterIncidenceSummary adapterIncidenceSummary = new AdapterIncidenceSummary(this, arrayListSummary);

    adapterIncidenceSummary.clear();
    adapterIncidenceSummary.notifyDataSetChanged();

    expandedListView = findViewById(R.id.listViewPestIncidence);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String ctrlNumber = intent.getStringExtra("ctrlNumber");
    String fieldNo = intent.getStringExtra("fieldNo");
    String variety = intent.getStringExtra("variety");
    String inspector = intent.getStringExtra("inspector");

     editText_ctrl_num = findViewById(R.id.editText_ctrl_number);
    TextInputEditText editText_field_no = findViewById(R.id.edittext_field_number);
    TextInputEditText editText_variety = findViewById(R.id.edittext_variety_planted);
    TextInputEditText editTextInspector = findViewById(R.id.edittext_inspector);

    editText_ctrl_num.setText(ctrlNumber);
    editText_field_no.setText(fieldNo);
    editText_variety.setText(variety);
    editTextInspector.setText(inspector);

    if (!ctrlNumber.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e("inside", "ctrl number not empty");

        dbf.child(ctrlNumber)
                .child("Crop Health")
                .child("Summary Incidence")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        SummaryPestQuadratHillIncidence summaryIncidence = new SummaryPestQuadratHillIncidence();
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            summaryIncidence = dataSnapshot1.getValue(SummaryPestQuadratHillIncidence.class);
                            arrayListSummary.add(summaryIncidence);
                            adapterIncidenceSummary.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            expandedListView.setAdapter(adapterIncidenceSummary);
                            Log.e("inside onDataChange", "FIRE");

                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


    } else {
        Log.e("Skipped", "control number is: " + ctrlNumber);
    }

}
```

I tried putting it inside a condition, the condition runs (printing the log) however the listener doesnt fire. But if i run it the second time, it works. I wonder whats the problem here.

Here's my data structure. The data inside the box is the one I need to get. When I first load the activity, data is not fetched. While pressing back and load again, the data is delivered.

[image]

Comment: Try to print value of `ctrlNumber` instead of only text

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Have you tried logging `databaseError` in the `onCancelled` handler? Does it throw any errors? Also, in your `onDataChange` handler, make sure to log/handle when  
`snapshot.hasChildren()` is `false`.

Comment: To help with Sam's question: the minimal `onCancelled` should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, I have uploaded the database structure.

Comment: @samthecodingman , snapshot.hasChildren() returns false, but it did print the ctrlNumber. But after going back to previous activity and loading the same activity again, snapshot.hasChildren() returns true and data were fetched. I'm really confused. I read that valueEventListners are asynchronous so I put a condition to check first if ctrlNumber is not empty. However, I can't understand this behaviour.

Comment: Sounds like when your activity is opened for the first time, `ctrlNumber` is set to a non-empty value, but to one that doesn't exist in the database resulting in `dataSnapshot.exists()` being false and having no children. When you return to the activity on later calls, `ctrlNumber` is set to a value that points to existing data and then works as expected.

Comment: Oh. I think I get it now. I placed the setVaue() and the activity change on the same function in the previous activity. So what's happening is that when method is called, activity change happens first before data is pushed to the firebase database. Thanks Sam for pointing that out. It's so fun learning!